# How to specify specific onComplete events for multipul lists with Mootools Sortables?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, mootools

How can I specify specific onComplete events for multipul lists with Mootools Sortables?

Like if you drag an item from list1 to list2 it will change the items NAME tag to something and if the same item is dragged from list2 back to list1 the NAME would change back to what it was before?

Nothing dynamic, just generic IDs. So if an item is in list1 its name is 'input_id' and if its dragged to list2 it should be changed to 'input_id2' and vice verse.

http://jsfiddle.net/nicekiwi/yrzgt/

Mootools 1.4.1

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Sortable`'s `dragOptions` option to setup some `Drag.Move` options. I made an example updating your fiddle, **[see here](http://jsfiddle.net/yrzgt/1/)**.

References **[here](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Drag/Sortables)** and **[here](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Drag/Drag.Move)**.

Answer (score 0):

```
var mod_sorting = function()
{
    new Sortables('#list1 ,#list2',
    {
        onComplete: function(el)
        {
            $$('#list1 li input').setProperty('name','input_id[]');
            $$('#list2 li input').setProperty('name','');
        }
    });
}
```